# Python2/Pygobject/Gtk3/Glade3 check TextView focus

Tags: python, gtk, glade, gtk3, pygobject

I'm designing a text editor-esque application using Python2.7 and Gtk3, and I'm not very sure on how to set up a handler to check if the main TextView is currently in focus, so I can disable menu items (e.g. Edit -> Copy etc.) accordingly.

In order to create the tabbed text editor, I use a Gtk.Notebook as the main body, and each time File -> New is activated I create a new ScrolledWindow and TextView to create a new tab in the text editor:

```
def on_imagemenuitemNew_activate(self, *args):
  editor = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
  editor.add(Gtk.TextView())
  editor.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)
  editor.show_all()
  #The instance of Gtk.Notebook is passed to the handler as user data in args[0]
  args[0].append_page(editor, Gtk.Label('untitled'))
```

This works fine but if I try to use:

```
editor.connect('focus-in-event', self.on_editor_focus_in_event)
```

inside the block then it is never registered by my handler:

```
def on_editor_focus_in_event(self, *args):
  print 'Focused!'
```

I suspect the issue may be due to each `editor` instance seemingly being identical but this really has me stumped. Forgive the sloppy coding, I only started learning GTK yesterday, and Pygobject/Gtk3 is not very well documented.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2012-February/msg00052.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `editor` is a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. I don't think `ScrolledWindow`s can have the focus. Try connecting to the focus-in event of your `TextView`, making sure to enable the correct mask as @TinaBrooks pointed out.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!
With this it also seems works without the mask.
I just needed to do this:
`editor.get_child().connect('focus-in-event', self.on_editor_focus_in_event)`

Answer (score 1):

I can only make a guess, but the documentation says that "to receive this signal, the GdkWindow associated to the widget needs to enable the `GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK` mask".

Are you sure you have it enabled?

Comment: In PyGObject, that particular enum is `Gdk.EventMask.FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK`
Also, it does not work even with that mask set.